# I want to make title required field while creating new row in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to make title field mandatory to save new row :-

```
<h1> Edit Post</h1>
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
<p>
   <br> <%= f.label :title, autofocus: true, placeholder: "title", :required => true %> <br/>
 <br> <%= f.text_field :title %> <br/>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :body %> <br/>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.submit "enter" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

It is saving anyway , kindly let me know where I am going wrong !

Comment: Do you have a presence validator defined in your model?

Comment: you can add model validation `validates :title, presence: true `

Answer (score 1):

On the frontend view you should have:

```
<h1> Edit Post</h1>
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
<p>
   <br> <%= f.label :title%> <br/>
 <br> <%= f.text_field :title, autofocus: true, placeholder: "title", required: true  %> <br/>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :body %> <br/>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.submit "enter" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Add a validation on your model as well, as such:

```
#models/post.rb
class Post
  validates :title, presence: true
end
```